# The right way to control a loop in QNX

Tags: c++, rtos, qnx

I'm starting a project on QNX. I'm not familiar with this OS. I'm writing a driver for an SPI external memory. There are plenty of polling loops on HW registers. What is the best way to control these loops to avoid the thread being stuck when the HW fails ?

I could start a timer and check whether it has timed out inside the loop condition but I am wondering if there isn't any easier way (like a watchdog: I didn't find a watchdog API except for the QNX hypervisor).

Advices welcome.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not always portable, the most common practice when using hardware polling loops is to use a loop counter based timeout.  The resolution of the software clock (milliseconds) is often much too large for most hardware timeout applications.

Example:

```
int wait_for_device() {
    unsigned loop_count = 0;
    while (poll_device() != DONE) {
        if (++loop_count == LOOP_TIMEOUT) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For most real-world device drivers, the time to perform the hardware IO cycle for the poll can be considered a lower bound on the loop timing for estimating appropriate timeouts.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is a classical solution. However I don't really like it. it makes the code less readable (although you might hide it inside a function or macro) and may create nasty bugs for example if you reduce or increase the CPU freq.  I was looking for a watchdog like solution.

Comment: QNX offers the nanospin_ns() function to support calibrated CPU busy-waits for standardizing loop timing.   It's approximately equivalent to the Linux kernel's ndelay() function.